# Hide Column in CellTable

Tags: gwt

How to hide the columns in Cell table? I need column for grouping purpose but don't want to show in table. Is there any way to hide? Any clue? See the below Code..

```
TextColumn<ContactInfor> ageTxt = new TextColumn<ContactInfor>() {
    @Override
    public String getValue(ContactInfor object) {
        return object.age;
    }
};
cellTable.addColumn(ageTxt, "AGE");

TextColumn<ContactInfor> empIdTxt = new TextColumn<ContactInfor>() {
    @Override
    public String getValue(ContactInfor object) {
        return object.empId;
    }
};
cellTable.addColumn(empIdTxt, "EMPLOYEE ID");

TextColumn<ContactInfor> addressTxt = new TextColumn<ContactInfor>() {
    @Override
    public String getValue(ContactInfor object) {
        return object.address;
    }
};
cellTable.addColumn(addressTxt, "ADDRESS");
```

Want to hide addressTxt column from cell table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide column in Cell table GWT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116758/how-to-hide-column-in-cell-table-gwt)

Comment: yup..I tried that solution but i did get still the column is visible

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't actually remove it from the table, perhaps just set the width to 0:

`cellTable.setColumnWidth(addressTxt, "0px");`

Javadocs: [http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html#setColumnWidth(com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.Column,java.lang.String)](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html#setColumnWidth(com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.Column,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: I tried with the above approach  like setting column width to "0px" still its not hiding,

Comment: I believe you have to set the whole table to a set width, or setting individual columns will not work: _The layout behavior depends on whether or not the table is using fixed layout._

Comment: I cant fixed the width for whole table, i am applying bootstrap to celltable to get responsiveness ..

Comment: You should probably just keep that data outside the table then, and use it to order the data before you populate the table.